# Would have been like

Tags: meaning

This is the final part of the story of someone who has NOT followed in her parents' footsteps. At times, she seems to regret not having done so. Here is how she feels:

"I wonder what being a doctor **would have been like**. **If only so** at parties I could receive admiration and respect, instead of being regarded as uninspiring and unimaginative."

I have no problem understanding the meaning of the sentence in general. However, from a grammatical point of view, I can't clearly figure out how those **bold** parts work and what exactly they mean.

Does *would have been like* refer to the third conditional clause? and what *if only so* mean?

Comment: ***if only so*** here means ***if for no other reason** than that [if I **had** been a doctor,] I'd get respect*. It's an idiomatically well established usage that carries the rather subtle implication that there ***might well be*** (probably ***are***) other reasons for doing something, but they're not significant. Even if there were no other reasons, just that one specified reason would be quite sufficient to justify taking the specified action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, (if I correctly remember what the "third conditional" means. It is a phrase that was completely unknown to me until I encountered it on this site. I believe it is used in ESL teaching, but it is unknown to most native speakers). It is an *irrealis*, or counterfactual conditional.

*So* here is a colloquial variant of *so that*. It is not part of a construction *if only so*.

Comment: Really interesting! For us, non-native speakers of English, passive voices are divided into four main types: zero, types one, two, and three. Apart from these, there are a number of mixed conditionals as well.

Comment: I don't think you mean "passive voices", @M.N; I think you mean "conditional clauses". And yes, from questions on this site, I have learnt that there is such a classification (though I've never come across 0 before). But to most English speakers, even if they have studied grammar, "third conditional" means nothing.

Comment: @ Colin Fine: Oh, my mistake! you're right.

Comment: A zero conditional, also known as factual conditional, "expresses a fixed connection that exists between two events now or always, e.g. If I wash the dishes, he dries them." (Oxford Practice Grammar by George Yule)